# Why the ScrollView is not working inside FlyoutHeaderTemplet?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

```
<Shell.FlyoutHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ScrollView>
             <StackLayout>
    .....................................
             <StackLayout/>
        <ScrollView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.FlyoutHeaderTemplate>
```

There is a lot of content inside the StackLayout which is being cut off.

Comment: *"which is being cut off."*  Not sure what that means. 1) Are you saying that you want the Flyout to be taller, to show more?  Or that there is "empty space" at bottom, where more content should be shown?  2) You might need to set VerticalOptions or HeightRequest somewhere, to be sure the ScrollView expands as much as it can. Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with Flyout to know exactly what is needed. 3) As a test, if you do  `<ScrollView HeightRequest="800" />`, what happens?

Comment: I tried giving the ScrollView height but still it is not letting me scroll to see the remaining content. I want to scroll it vertically.

Answer (score -1):

I did a test on sample [Xaminals](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/UserInterface/Xaminals) according to your code,and used the following code ,it worked normally.

You can refer to the following code:

```
    <Shell.FlyoutHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HeightRequest="600" BackgroundColor="DarkGreen">
                <Image Aspect="AspectFill" 
                   Source="watermelon.png" 
                       HeightRequest="550"
                       WidthRequest="550"
                   Opacity="0.6" />
                <Label Text="test header" 
                   TextColor="White" 
                   FontAttributes="Bold" 
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />

            </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.FlyoutHeaderTemplate>
```

The result is:
[image]

Comment: We have the same problem and it's intermittent, sometimes it scrolls sometimes it doesn't. So having it work once proves nothing other than your lucky.